# What is the contrapositive of this simple proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> If $a$ and $b$ are rational then $ab$ and $a+b$ are also rational.

What is the contrapositive of this proposition?

1. If $ab$ and $a+b$ are not rational then $a$ and $b$ are not rational.
2. If $ab$ or $a+b$ are not rational then $a$ or $b$ are not rational.

Comment: Second one: the negation of $p \text { and } q$ is $\text{not-}p \text { or } 
 \text{not-}q$

Comment: The negation of a conjunction is a disjunction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easiest to formulate your statement in symbolic form then interpret: $$(a \in \mathbb{Q} \land b \in \mathbb{Q} ) \Rightarrow (ab \in \mathbb{Q} \land a+b \in \mathbb{Q})$$ therefore the contrapositive is $$\lnot (ab \in \mathbb{Q} \land a+b \in \mathbb{Q}) \Rightarrow \lnot (a \in \mathbb{Q} \land b \in \mathbb{Q} )$$ or equivalently $$(\lnot ab \in \mathbb{Q} \lor \lnot a+b \in \mathbb{Q}) \Rightarrow (\lnot a \in \mathbb{Q} \lor \lnot b \in \mathbb{Q} ).$$

It's a little unclear to which of your statements this corresponds (ambiguity in your English, at least to me), but I think your (b) is correct. That is, I think your (b) means "If $ab$ is not rational or $a + b$ is not rational then $a$ is not rational or $b$ is not rational."

As a side note, I'm never sure if the use of "are" in English (as in the question) implies parentheses. Maybe someone else can chime in to clear up that point for me to make this a more complete answer.

Comment: I think "are", as used above, is just poor English and was probably just an oversight when copy/pasting (1) to (2) and changing "and"s to "or"s.

Comment: Yes, **is** would make more sense (independent of English). But what would be the alternative interpretation of *are*? That, the not does not apply to $ab$?

Comment: I have trouble not seeing it as "the statement ($ab \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $a+b \in \mathbb{Q}$) *is* not true," which would be the same as "$\lnot$ ($ab \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $a+b \in \mathbb{Q}$)" but when I take my time I see that *are* gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your statement: $a$ and $b$ rational $\implies$ ($ab$ and $a+b$) rational.

Contrapositive: not ($a+b$ and $ab$ rational) $\equiv$ not ($a+b$ rational) or not ($ab$ rational) $\implies$ not($a$ and $b$ rational) $\equiv$ not ($a$ rational) or not ($b$ rational).

(My initial answer had a silly mistake in it)

Comment: There is an "and" also In "a  and b are rational".

Comment: Indeed, thanks.